# Many similar methods vs one method that takes many parameters?

Tags: python, class, methods, enums, arguments

I am having a hard time deciding between the options on how to write this client below:

```
import requests
```

1. Mehtod dependent:

```
class Client:

    def request_endpoint_1(self, **params):
        return requests.get('url_1', params)

    def request_endpoint_2(self, **params):
        return requests.get('url_2', params)
    
    def request_endpoint_3(self, **params):
        return requests.get('url_3', params)
    .
    .
    .
```

2. Argument dependent:

```
from enum import Enum


class Endpoint(Enum):
    endpoint_1 = 'url_1'
    endpoint_2 = 'url_2'
    endpoint_3 = 'url_3'
    .
    .
    .


class Client:

    def request(self, endpoint: Endpoint, **params):
        return requests.get(endpoint.value, params)
```

Considering the endpoint count is very high (100+), the 2nd option seems like a better choice since it repeats significantly less and I am guessing that the memory allocation for the enums is also less than the same number of instance methods in 1st option.

But if I take option 1, This makes it IDE-friendly and more simple to write code using `Client` methods. With option 2, the user also has to import the `Endpoint(Enum)` class which will be in a different module than `Client`.

The question is which one should I use, and why?
I also want to learn if there's considerable memory efficiency difference between the two.

Comment: Do both. Option one is the public facing class, which has explicit and documented parameters. Option two is the base class, which handles the actual execution and logging. The enum may be unnecessary, but can help in the logging. Runtime differences is unlikely, and would be dwarfed by the request anyway.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Each method actually has a few more parameters in addition to the url. Each enum would be a tuple in this case like: `(url, method, auth_type, ...)`

Comment: It's a lot easier to put named parameters on a method, with a docstring and type hints.

Comment: @KennyOstrom So defining hundreds of methods with a lot of repeating of `def...return requests.get(... **params)` is considered good practice?

Comment: I didn't post an answer because it's just my opinion, but you're missing the important part. Each of those hundreds of methods are clearly documenting an entire api call, along with their specific parameters. So yes. As long as they're documenting the api that you kind of need to document anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good API should be self-explanatory just by reading the method signatures, and neither approaches in your question offer a good idea of what each endpoint is expecting and returning, namely the parameters and returning values.

It would be a lot clearer to write one method for each endpoint, with properly named and typed parameters. Each method should also return a value of a data type that's suited to the nature of the call instead of a generic `Response` object. Also store common parameters as instance attributes when initializing the client object.

So to answer the title of the question "Many similar methods vs one method that takes many parameters?", I would say the better approach is to write "many dissimilar methods".

For example (using some imaginary storage API):

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self, auth_key: str):
        self.common_params = {'auth_key': auth_key}

    def list_directory(self, path: str, recursive: bool = False) -> list[str]:
        return [
            file['name']
            for file in requests.get('url_1', params={
                'path': path,
                'recursive': 'yes' if recursive else 'no',
                **self.common_params
            }).json()['files']
        ]

    def copy_file(self, from_path: str, to_path: str) -> None:
        requests.get('url_2', params={
            'from_path': from_path,
            'to_path': to_path,
            **self.common_params
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should've better demonstrated what each method looks like in more detail as they looked shallow while I was aiming for question simplicity.

Comment: Do you think that python would allocate too much memory to be inefficient if there were about 500 methods just like the two in your answer? I'll probably stick to methods anyway but this was my main concern.

Comment: The amount of memory occupied by compiled bytecodes is typically tiny compared to actual user data, and 500 methods aren't that many as long as they serve distinctly different purposes. The documentation of your client API, however, should break down the 500 methods by categories, for easier navigation.

Comment: Feel free to update your question with a more meaningful example of an API that demonstrates the nature of the 500 methods you're dealing with. At this point they look too generic to tell if they warrant a different programming pattern.

Comment: Your example mimics the nature of my methods well. Mine are even less complex since I return the response as the server sends it. It's up to the user to do whatever with it. Methods only get complex when they have unique parameters to process and send.